# media foundation h264 encoder setinputmediatype fails with invalid media type

Tags: video, h.264, ms-media-foundation, encoder

I posted my issue on MS Media Foundation forum, and so far no one was able to respond. I have seen similar threads to my issue on MS forums and Stackoverflow but I did not find any resolutions.
I have setup a pipeline with couple of transforms. The purpose of this pipeline is to be able to customize the components i.e. swapping the media sinks and transform with custom components vs built ins.

My issue is with the H264 encoder. Decoder works fine. I enum the encoders. It returns one H264 encoder. I have tried setting up the media types in two ways. FYI Output Media type gets set properly. Per MS documentation the output needs to be set first. I only set the IMFTranform attributes and not the ICodecAPI attrbs. Once the output is set, I move to the input.

Two ways are: 
1) create blanks media types, set the attrbs and apply them 2) or get the available input type and then modify the attributes that I am interested in such as frame width, height, frame rate and interlace mode. SetInputType fails with C00D36D5 (invalid media type). Not sure why. MFTrace states a failure but does not give any reason on what is missing. Any ideas?
Here is the sample code with setting up from scratch:

```
HRESULT MediaFoundationManager::FindEncoder(IMFTransform **decoder, IMFMediaType *type)
{
            HRESULT hr = S_OK;
            UINT32 count = 0;

            CLSID *ppCLSIDs = NULL;

            MFT_REGISTER_TYPE_INFO info = { 0 };
            info.guidMajorType = MFMediaType_Video;
            info.guidSubtype = MFVideoFormat_YUY2;

            MFT_REGISTER_TYPE_INFO outInfo = {0};
            outInfo.guidMajorType = MFMediaType_Video;
            outInfo.guidSubtype = MFVideoFormat_H264;

            hr = MFTEnum(    MFT_CATEGORY_VIDEO_ENCODER,
                    0,          // Reserved
                    &info,       // Input type
                    &outInfo,      // Output type
                    NULL,       // Reserved
                    &ppCLSIDs,
                    &count
                    );

                if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && count == 0)
                    hr = MF_E_TOPO_CODEC_NOT_FOUND;


                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    hr = CoCreateInstance(ppCLSIDs[0], NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_PPV_ARGS(decoder));

                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    ConfigureMFTFromScratch(*decoder,info.guidSubtype,outInfo.guidSubtype, true);                    
                }
            }

            CoTaskMemFree(ppCLSIDs);
            return hr;
 }

void MediaFoundationManager::ConfigureMFTFromScratch(IMFTransform *transform, GUID inputFormat, GUID outputFormat, bool h264)
{
            CComPtr<IMFMediaType> inputMediaType = NULL;
            CComPtr<IMFMediaType> outputMediaType = NULL;

            Helper::CheckHR(MFCreateMediaType(&inputMediaType),"Create Media Type");
            Helper::CheckHR(MFCreateMediaType(&outputMediaType),"Create Media Type");

            Helper::CheckHR(inputMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video),"Set major type");
            Helper::CheckHR(inputMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, inputFormat),"Set Sub type");
            Helper::CheckHR(MFSetAttributeSize(inputMediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE,_inputInfo.FrameWidth, _inputInfo.FrameHeight),"Set Frame Size");
            Helper::CheckHR(inputMediaType->SetUINT64(MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, _inputInfo.FrameRate),"Set Frame rate");
            Helper::CheckHR(inputMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, _inputInfo.BitRate),"Set Bit rate");
            Helper::CheckHR(inputMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlaceMode::MFVideoInterlace_Progressive),"Set Interlace Mode");
            Helper::CheckHR(MFSetAttributeRatio(inputMediaType, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1),"Set Aspect Ratio");

            Helper::CheckHR(outputMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video),"Set major type");
            Helper::CheckHR(outputMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, outputFormat),"Set Sub type");
            Helper::CheckHR(MFSetAttributeSize(outputMediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE,_inputInfo.FrameWidth, _inputInfo.FrameHeight),"Set Frame Size");
            Helper::CheckHR(outputMediaType->SetUINT64(MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, _inputInfo.FrameRate),"Set Frame rate");
            Helper::CheckHR(outputMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, _inputInfo.BitRate),"Set Bit rate");
            Helper::CheckHR(outputMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlaceMode::MFVideoInterlace_Progressive),"Set Interlace Mode");
            Helper::CheckHR(MFSetAttributeRatio(outputMediaType, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1),"Set Aspect Ratio");    

            if (h264)
            {
                UINT32 level = -1;
                outputMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_MPEG2_LEVEL, level);
                Helper::CheckHR(outputMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_MPEG2_PROFILE , eAVEncH264VProfile_Main),"Set Profile Mode");
                Helper::CheckHR(transform->SetOutputType(0, outputMediaType, 0),"Set output type");    
                Helper::CheckHR(transform->SetInputType(0, inputMediaType, 0),"Set input type");                    
            }
            else
            {        
                Helper::CheckHR(transform->SetInputType(0, inputMediaType, 0),"Set input type");    
                Helper::CheckHR(transform->SetOutputType(0, outputMediaType, 0),"Set output type");                    
            }
}
```

I really appreciate if you guys point me to the right direction.

Comment: Please include your sample code directly in the question rather than linking to an external forum.

Comment: @b4hand: Sorry, I will add it. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried specifying more verbose output for the MFTrace? Topoedit is also a good tool to test your topology.

Comment: @AlekseyKabanov-MSFT Yes, MFtrace would only mention of a failure. I managed to resolve the issue which kind of contradicts with the documentation. Well not totally.

Comment: @AlekseyKabanov-MSFT Any attempt to set the Input type with any modified Media Type fails. If I GetOutputAvailableType, add the required attributes, the MPEG Sequence header blob gets added properly. Then I proceed to getting an input instance through GetInputavailableType. Setting the input using the returned instance will work fine. As soon as I modify an attribute, SetInputType will fail. I guess the encoder perform a deep reference comparison of the media type and the internal one. That is the only thing I can think of.

Comment: H264 encoder internally calls into the [IsEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms696980(v=vs.85).aspx), which is not reference comparison. It cares about the MF_MEDIATYPE_EQUAL_MAJOR_TYPES and MF_MEDIATYPE_EQUAL_FORMAT_TYPES flags. Then it checks MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, and MF_MT_MINIMUM_DISPLAY_APERTURE (and couple of others to validate it against the output type). Maybe the last one caused the issue you observed.

Comment: @AlekseyKabanov-MSFT Thanks for the info. The only weird thing is that If I SetGuid on MF_MT_SUB_TYPE or MAJORTYPE for the input, SetInputType fails. I guess there might be something set in each available media type that is sensitive to change. Again thanks for the info. As for now getting a desired available input and setting it works fine.